# firebase react-native auth always ask for authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am using firebase for react-native

I created a account with firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword

everything works fine also using firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword

everything works fine but if is restart my app and i watch to see firebase current user

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
        if(user) console.log("user")
        else console.log("no user")
      })
```

it returns no user i am not able to understand why it is doing like this. i am using  "firebase": "^6.2.3",

Comment: are you signing out?

Comment: no i am not doing logout. it's automatcally logout

Comment: when i open app again. firebase user is null. i am not able to understand why.